# Error on wrong artisan command

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.3, laravel-artisan

I know whenever someone types wrong artisan command a well-formatted error message is shown

But there is some problem in my project because when I run wrong command eg

```
php artisan create:migration create_table
```

I am getting this output

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught UnexpectedValueException: The stream or file "/home/amarjit/Documents/localhost/inkpothub/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/amarjit/Documents/localhost/inkpothub/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php:107
Stack trace:
#0 /home/amarjit/Documents/localhost/inkpothub/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/AbstractProcessingHandler.php(37): Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler->write(Array)
#1 /home/amarjit/Documents/localhost/inkpothub/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(337): Monolog\Handler\AbstractProcessingHandler->handle(Array)
#2 /home/amarjit/Documents/localhost/inkpothub/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(616): Monolog\Logger->addRecord(400, Object(UnexpectedValueException), Array)
#3 /home/amarjit/Documents/localhost/inkpothub/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/Writer.php(202): Monolog\Logger->error(Object(UnexpectedValueException), Array)
#4 /home/amarjit/Documents/localhost/inkpothu in /home/amarjit/Documents/localhost/inkpothub/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php on line 107
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught UnexpectedValueException: The stream or file "/home/amarjit/Documents/localhost/inkpothub/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/amarjit/Documents/localhost/inkpothub/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php:107
Stack trace:
#0 /home/amarjit/Documents/localhost/inkpothub/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/AbstractProcessingHandler.php(37): Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler->write(Array)
#1 /home/amarjit/Documents/localhost/inkpothub/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(337): Monolog\Handler\AbstractProcessingHandler->handle(Array)
#2 /home/amarjit/Documents/localhost/inkpothub/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(616): Monolog\Logger->addRecord(400, Object(Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException), Array)
#3 /home/amarjit/Documents/localhost/inkpothub/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/Writer.php(202): Monolog\Logger->error(Object(Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorExcept in /home/amarjit/Documents/localhost/inkpothub/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php on line 107
```

its only happening with one of my Laravel-5.3 project. Therefore the issue is not related with my localhost

Comment: Are You On Production Or On Development Mode ?

Comment: I am on Development mode

Comment: Your Problem Is Related To Permission Try `sudo chmod -R 775 /to/your/laravel/folder/root`

Comment: in the error it's saying about storage folder therefore I executed this command on storage folder only

Comment: also as per documentation only storage and bootstrap/cache folder should have 775 access.

Comment: Either Well Work Just To Make Sure This Affected

Comment: Have You Tried?

Comment: You Are In Development  Mode No Need To Be Very Afraid!

Comment: Ok, I tried sudo chmod -R 775 on laravel directory But still same error

Comment: @AmarjitSingh which OS are you using ? and try `php artisan cache:clear`

Comment: I am using Ubuntu